# Help with sound issue on gpu

Tags: nvidia, sound

new to linux and having issues detecting other sound devices since installing my gpu. When using the built in it gives me the several options available and my headset will work, with my gpu i only get sound through my tv i have hooked up to the pc

This is the only option available with my gpu:

HDMI/DisplayPort 2
GK104 HDMI Audio Controller

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bit and specs are

Intel i5-6500

Evga Geforce GTX 660 TI

Gigabyte z170-HD3

8GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4

Samsung Evo 250gb SSD

Evga 500w Bronze

i am using the Nvidia 352.63 proprietary driver tested, gaming is working fine on the video side of things just wish to use my headset! Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

well i found a fix, if anyone is having the same issue with newer hardware and sound

follow the information in these links:

https://www.pantz.org/hardware/motherboard/intel_skylake_with_an_asus_z170-ar_and_ubuntu_linux_14.04.html

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS